# Halcon - speed up Intersection

Tags: intersection, contour, halcon

I have a XLD contour, for semplicity imagine a circle with a hole, like a doughnut... (in reality its a organic shape.. its just to simplify...)

I draw lines across this circle at a certain angle, and need to find the two outermost intersections of the lines with the circle. I do it like this:

```
gen_contour_polygon_xld (Line,[curYL,curYR],[x1,x2])
intersection_contours_xld(Line,CircleXld,'all',Y,X,overlapping)
```

and then pick the first and last values from the Y and X tuples.

The `intersection_contours_xld` takes 2.39 ms on average.. I need to run this 15 times per picture, and have a total of 6 pictures. Is there a faster way to do this? It is eating up too much time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one is much faster with only 0.011ms..

```
intersection_line_contour_xld(CrateRegionXld,curYL,x1,curYR,x2,Y,X,overlapping)
```